# Using reflection to find and use a method using unknown generic type

Tags: f#

Consider this function

```
let bar : 'a -> int = 
    fun _ -> 1
```

and this function

```
let foo : unit -> string = 
    fun () -> "its fine"
```

and then the composition (notice the type 'a, disappears, its specific type doesnt matter)

```
let fooBar : unit -> int = 
    fun () -> bar (foo ())
```

I have code that uses reflection to find the "foo" method, but not actually know the return type of that function and will the immediately wrap this function to consume the unknown return type (actually its an unknown parameter in some generic type, but the above example suffices).

BUT how do I do this?

my code looks a bit like the below,

```
let composeReflectedMethod : string -> (unit -> int) = 
    let dll = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "foo.dll")); 
    let ``type`` = dll.GetType("Foo")
    let fooMethod = ``type``.GetMethod("foo")
    // I don't know what the return type is ? but logically I dont need to.
    // but whatever it is I know I can handle it.
    // but in its absence it will be obj
    let ifooWhat = 
        fooMethod.
            Invoke(
                null,
                [| () |]) 
    // and this line wont compile
    fun () -> bar ifooWhat
```

P.S. the actual real code is much more complex than this, so ignore the fact that the above code seems pointless.

P.P.S.

the above example implies that the code actually doesnt use the return type, and thus the actual type doesnt matter, this isnt the case, I can simply use 'obj' as the type, its irritatingly difficult to make a simple example that demonstrates the issue without it being really complex.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET you can't just straight up call a generic method (which is what `bar` compiles to). In fact, you can't call a generic method *at all*. You can only *instantiate* a generic method - i.e. create a non-generic version of it for specific choices of type variables, - and only then you can call that instantiation.

How to find the method you already know. To instantiate a method, use `MakeGenericMethod` and give it the generic variable(s) choice(s). Then use `Invoke` to call the instantiation:

```
type A =
    static member bar x = "It's a " + x.GetType().Name

let genericBar = typeof<A>.GetMethod("bar")

let barOfString = genericBar.MakeGenericMethod(typeof<string>)
barOfString.Invoke(null, [| "foo" |])
> "It's a String"

let barOfInt = genericBar.MakeGenericMethod(typeof<int>)
barOfInt.Invoke(null, [| 42 |])
> "It's a Int32"
```

So in your case you would do something like:

```
...GetMethod("bar")
    .MakeGenericMethod(ifooWhat.GetType())
    .Invoke(null, [| ifooWhat |])
```

But don't forget to handle the case of `ifooWhat == null`

---

I must note that I am not sure you even need all of that. After all, if `bar` doesn't care about its parameter *at all*, then why does it even have one? I suspect that in reality `bar` cares about its parameter in sort of a type-less way. Perhaps it just calls `ToString` on it. Or checks it for `null`. Or something like that. If that's the case, then just make the parameter `obj`. After all, any type-less sort of use would effectively box it into `obj` anyway.

Comment: in the PPS it states not to take the code too literally, the example code does ignore its parameter, the real code doesnt. I have code like you do above, and its just this MakeGenericMethod step that I can't do because I dont know the type, even though it will be wrapped and hidden. The code does care about its type (its effectively a tagless encoding and reflects on this type)....but all that complexity doesnt really matter. I know nothing about things like code quotations, and whether you could somehow stitch the two pieces together without explicitly knowing the type

Comment: oh, wait, let me try what you have suggested...I think you have suggested something, I just need to see if i can apply it

Comment: hmmmm...this is going to be complicated.....the types are much more complex than the example, it may take me a while to get to the point where it will work or not. But i understand the principle. Note "bar" is actually known to the code, but you are suggesting using reflection to invoke it?

Comment: 1. Yes, you can call `MakeGenericMethod` because yes, you do know the type - it's `ifooWhat.GetType()` like I wrote in my example. 2. If `bar` only reflects on the type, then its formal parameter can be `obj`. Think about it.

Comment: just checking, I wasnt expecting "make" 2 methods, but that works in my head